# How do you sort a contact list in alphabetical order using actionlistener in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, actionlistener

I have a java assignment that I am supposed to sort a sample contact list in alphabetical order from last name to first name including their phone numbers. I have been trying to use things like lastName, firstName, nameList, and numberList but still wasn't able to get right information to have the list sorted in alphabetical order from last name to first name. It would be nice if I could get some help or a hint to help me forward. I'm currently also using a actionlistener to help me with sorting the list.

Here is part of the constructor code.

```
public class ContactList extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener {

    JMenuItem newMI, openMI, saveMI, saveAsMI, exitMI;
    JMenuItem searchMI, deleteMI, updateMI, newEntryMI, sortMI;
    JTextField lastName, firstName, phoneNumber;
    JList<String> listView;
    DefaultListModel<String> nameList = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    Vector<String> numberList = new Vector<String>();
    File currentFile = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ContactList() {
        super("Phone Contacts");          // set frame title
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());    // set layout

        // create menu bar
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        // create file menu
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(fileMenu);
        newMI = fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("New"));
        newMI.addActionListener(this);
        openMI = fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Open"));
        openMI.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        saveMI = fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));
        saveAsMI = fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Save As ..."));
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        exitMI = fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Exit"));
        exitMI.addActionListener(this);

        // create edit menu
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menubar.add(editMenu);
        updateMI = editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Update"));
        updateMI.addActionListener(this);
        newEntryMI = editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("New Entry"));
        newEntryMI.addActionListener(this);
        deleteMI = editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Delete"));
        deleteMI.addActionListener(this);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        searchMI = editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Search"));
        searchMI.addActionListener(this);
        sortMI = editMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sort"));
        sortMI.addActionListener(this);

        // create phone list and controls
        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Name List", JLabel.LEFT);
        listPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        listView = new JList<String>(nameList);
        listView.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        listView.addListSelectionListener(this);
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(listView);
        listPanel.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JPanel editPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        panel.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        label = new JLabel("Last Name", Label.LEFT);
        editPanel.add(label);
        lastName = new JTextField();
        editPanel.add(lastName);
        label = new JLabel("First Name", Label.LEFT);
        editPanel.add(label);
        firstName = new JTextField();
        editPanel.add(firstName);
        label = new JLabel("Phone Number", Label.LEFT);
        editPanel.add(label);
        phoneNumber = new JTextField();
        editPanel.add(phoneNumber);
    }
```

Here is the actionlistener code for the assignment. Also I don't need to sort the phone numbers. Just the last name to first name. The sources comes from the sortMI issue that I was trying to figure out.

```
// implementing ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if(source == newMI) {
            nameList.clear();
            numberList.clear();
            currentFile = null;
            display(-1);
            setTitle("Phone Contacts");   // reset frame title
        }
        else if(source == openMI) {
            doOpen();
        }
        else if(source == deleteMI) {
            nameList.remove(getState());
            numberList.remove(getName());
        }
        else if(source == exitMI) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(source == updateMI) {
            int index = listView.getSelectedIndex();
            String name = lastName.getText().trim() + " " + firstName.getText().trim();
            String number = phoneNumber.getText().trim();
            if(index < 0) {  // add a new entry
                nameList.addElement(name);
                numberList.addElement(number);
                index = nameList.getSize()-1;
            }
            else {  // update an existing entry
                nameList.set(index, name);
                numberList.set(index, number);        
            }
            listView.setSelectedIndex(index);
            listView.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
        }
        else if(source == newEntryMI) {
            listView.clearSelection();
            display(-1);
        }
        else if(source == searchMI) {
            String searchName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                                "Please enter a name (last first) to search:");
            System.out.println("Name to search: " + searchName);
            nameList.contains(searchName);
            return;
        }
        else if(source == sortMI) {
            lastName.getText(); 
            firstName.getText();
        }
    }
```

I did also look for other examples of sorting in java but it didn't involve one with actionlistener.

Comment: You want to sort `nameList`, correct?

Comment: Yeah the nameList to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use method [copyInto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#copyInto-java.lang.Object:A-), in class `DefaultListModel`, to get the contents of `nameList` as an array.
- Use method [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-), in class `java.util.Arrays`, to sort the array.
- Create a new `DefaultListModel` from the sorted array.
- Set the model for `listView`.

```java
Object[] objs = nameList.copyInto();
Arrays.sort(objs, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            String s1 = o1 == null ? "" : o1.toString();
            String s2 = o2 == null ? "" : o2.toString();
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    });
nameList = new DefaultListModel(objs);
listView.setModel(nameList);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```java
Object[] objs = nameList.copyInto();
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(objs)
                          .map(obj -> obj == null ? "" : obj.toString())
                          .sorted()
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
Vector<Object> v = new Vector<>(list);
nameList = new DefaultListModel(v);
listView.setModel(nameList);
```